# SQL GOTO statement in a script with multiple GO

Tags: t-sql, goto, raiseerror

I need to exit a SQL script without an error if a certain condition holds true. I've read that 1 solution would be to `raiseerror` with error code 20+ and `with log` parameter. But the limitation for that is that i can execute that only as an admin and the connection to the db will be aborted.

Also, I tried using GOTO and jump to the end-of-the-script, but it doesnt work, because I have multiple GO in the middle of the script. Is there a another solution?

`IF  <some condition>
BEGIN

    GOTO Finished;

END

GO`

`Finished:

    SELECT 'Done'`

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `GOTO` in SQL. Did you perhaps mean a specific dialect?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - t-sql has a GOTO statement.

Comment: yeah, t-sql. If I declare the label before I jump to it, then everything is ok. Otherwise, it complains that it is undeclared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`goto` cannot jump past a `go`.  You'd have to retest the condition in each block:

```
IF NOT <some condition> 
BEGIN
   ...
END
GO
IF NOT <some condition> 
BEGIN
   ...
END
GO
IF NOT <some condition> 
...
```

Comment: +1, it is either this or use `EXEC(@SQL)` for this things that need the GO, and then you can use the `GOTO`.